# Log4j 1.x to 2.x migration for JDBCAppender

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate an application from log4j v1.2 to v2.17. In that application, they are using JDBCAppender in Java through import and are extending it to a class and doing some operations.
How can we do this using 2.17? They are using fields like connection, buffer, etc. which is available in 1.2 but not in 2.17. How can we set it as the values are dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

JDBCAppender cannot be mapped to Log4j 2's JdbcAppender. You have to rewrite it.

The JDBC Appender configured with a DataSource requires JNDI support.

to allow it you need to add this to the configuration:

```
log4j2.enableJndiJdbc=true
```

There is more info about JDBC appenders in version 2.x:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#jdbcappender

I would also read this migration guide:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Comment: These links give me details on what it is and how to migrate for xml. The JdbcAppender I’m working on is configured in Java. A class is created and it’s extending the older version of JDBCAppender. If I try to do the same thing with the new version, it is failing. I’m looking for steps to do this